# When do GCP cloud functions acknowledge pub/sub messages?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a cloud function that gets triggered from a pub/sub message. This function never explicitly acknowledges the message in the source code.

So when does this function acknowledge the pub/sub message if the acknowledgement never happens in the source code?

Update: when a function crashes, I understand that a message acknowledgement shouldn't occur and yet a new function invocation for that message never appears in the logs

**Reproducible Example**

- Create a pubsub topic called **test_topic**
- Create a cloud function called **test_function** with trigger test_topic. Give it all the default settings including NOT retrying on failure. In the code itself, set the language to **python3.7** with entry point of **hello_pubsub** and the following code:

  ```
   import base64
   def hello_pubsub(event, context):
       pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
       print(pubsub_message)
       raise RuntimeError('error in function')
  ```
- The **requirements.txt** remains blank
- Go into test_topic and publish a message with **go** as the text.
- There will be an error in the test_function logs. However there will only be one function invocation with the error and this will remain the case even after a few days or so.

Comment: guillaume answer is not fully correct. The event driven functions default behaviour is to ack pub/sub both in the case of success/failure. If you want your cloud function to be retried on failure, you should enable "--retry" parameter. Best practices for using retry can be found here -> https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#best_practices

Comment: I think that's what he says in his edit

Comment: but isn't the statement  "If the function exits in error, the message is NACK" wrong ?

Comment: Yes you are right that is incorrect

Answer (score 4):

If the function finish gracefully, the message is acknowledge. If the function exits in error, the message is NACK.

---

**EDIT 1**

I have tested with a Go background function. You need to deploy your cloud function with the parameter `--retry` to allow the messages in error to be retried. Else, the messages aren't retried.

In Go, here the cases where retried are performed:

- Return an Error (equivalent to exception in Java or Python), status "error" in the logs
- Perform a log.Fatal() (exit the function (function crash) with a specific log) status "connection error" in the logs
- Perform an explicit exit, status "connection error" in the logs

Here the code (if interested)

```
type PubSubMessage struct {
    Data []byte `json:"data"`

}

func PubsubError(ctx context.Context, m PubSubMessage) error {

    switch string(m.Data) {
    case "ok":
        return nil
    case "error":
        return errors.New("it's an error")
    case "fatal":
        log.Fatal("crash")
    case "exit":
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    return nil
}
```

And how i deployed my Cloud Functions

```
gcloud beta functions deploy --runtime=go113 --trigger-topic=test-topic \
  --source=function --entry-point=PubsubError --region=us-central1 \
  --retry pubsuberror
```

Comment: What does gracefully mean in this case. Does a manually raised exception count as gracefully?

Comment: No, if you raise an exception, without catching it in the function, the  function exit in error.

Comment: For functions that I have deployed this doesn't seem to be the case. If a function crashes a new one doesn't spin up later as I would expect. Or perhaps the retry flag has to be set to True for this to occur?

Comment: The retry is automatic, with an exponential backoff

Comment: so if a pub/sub message triggers a function and that function crashes, shouldn't you see several examples of the function crashing in the logs, not just the one?

Comment: Yes. it should. Share you code if you want I have a look or a try on my side

Comment: That would be amazing if you could! I have included an example in my question

Comment: Yes I have this in my todo, not yet the time to do it!

Comment: The docs say "Note: Cloud Functions acks the Pub/Sub message internally upon successful function invocation. When retries are enabled, Cloud Functions can re-invoke a function that has failed during execution using the same Pub/Sub message." This would suggest it isn't when a function finishes gracefully. See here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#sample_code

Comment: Tested, you need the --retry param. See my answer update.

Comment: The statement "If the function exits in error, the message is NACK." is incorrect. Even if it exits in error the message is still acknowledged.

Comment: What's the exit in error for you?

Comment: Maybe its more semantic but I think the message is acknowledged on successful invocation and then you can retry the function if it fails. But the message is acknowledged.

Comment: for push subscriptions where do we see/check if a message is acknowledged or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this description:
[Google Cloud Pub/Sub Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub)

> Cloud Functions acks the Pub/Sub message internally upon successful function invocation.

I do understand that documentation quotation as the acknowledgement happens only after the execution of code is finished without any (uncatched) errors.

At the same time, while the execution might still be 'in progress', the Pub/Sub service may make a decision to trigger another cloud function (instance) from the same Pub/Sub message.

Some additional details are in this Issue Tracker dicussion:
[Cloud Function explicit acknowledgement of a pubsub message](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534854)

From my point of view, independently from 'successful' or 'not successful' the invocation happened, the cloud function is to be developed in an idempopent way, taking into account 'at least once delivery' paradigm of the Pub/Sub service. In other words the cloud function is to be developed in a such a way, that multiple invocations from one message are handled correctly.